# Should you inform the higher-ups if you believe that a (lower) supervisor didn't follow the correct procedure to force a resignation?

Tags: united-states, termination

Someone got the boot from a supervisor which clearly was not informed of the actual work of the employee (all the reasons for termination/forced resignation where one-sided and didn't really stand to evidence). This supervisor has a supervisor. Should the employee just keep his evidence of a misinformed decision to himself and walk away giving thanks for the time there? Or should they write a letter to the higher-ups informing of their work and how this event didn't make sense/was uncalled for?

Edit: This is in US

Comment: Do you want to use the supervisor as a reference by any chance, or do you care much what the company thinks of you? What would be your goal? Getting the supervisor fired? Getting your job back? Both? Is the evidence actual evidence or is it just you presenting your case (the latter would turn it into a he-said-she-said situation)?

Comment: "Someone got the boot"? Who was that someone? Was it you? Or was it someone else? If it was someone else, the answer may be different than if it was you.

Comment: Usually in the US, termination is a compilation of all work done that did not match the company expectations and rarely it is about "one" occasion of a project. Can you include more information to your post to include location + projects that your "friend" completed but you believe Supervisor is not informed?.

Comment: @Isaiah3015 - To expand on your point, it's a compilation of all work done, because making a decision on a single action could open a company to unlawful termination issue in some cases.

Answer (score 5):

Because rewriting this whole post is hard and this is an edit, I'm just going to clarify that the below advice is for the person who was terminated, not yourself.

Seek legal counsel.

If the presented reasons for termination are provably and demonstrably false, you may have a legal case against the employer for wrongful/illegal termination.  I would avoid writing anything to the employer because you never know what could be used against you in a court of law, but I would seek legal advice regarding whether or not you have a case based on evidence you have collected.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly many times in real life doing good work and even getting on well with other employees isn't enough... But it certainly should be.

I would be very careful, though, of escalating things until you know the full facts. The question here might not be directly about the ethics straight away, but rather, what can you personally do to make sure no-one is unethically dismissed in future?

If you are doing well and have a secure position in the company, I would suggest you bide your time, go play by play and try to make a positive difference in an intelligent manner. Don't go all guns blazing until you are sure you are right and can win.

Writing a letter, documenting etc are all situational calls. Make the right one and you'll make sure the company changes for the better and most will thank you for it.